# How to use UUID instead of a slug for ticket

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am currently navigating to a ticket using the slug set by the title example `blah-blah-blah` and want to use `uuid` instead of `336c64de-5dcb-34bc-9511-a48242b9zzzb`. What is the best approach to take for Laravel 8? I am using Laravel Jetstream with Livewire stack.

**Current model code**

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

public function setSlugAttribute($slug)
{
    $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($slug);
}

public function path()
{
    return '/tickets/' . $this->slug;
}
```

**Ticket Migration**

```
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id');
    $table->foreignId('ticket_type_id');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->string('email')->nullable();
    $table->string('url')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('locked')->default(false);
    $table->unsignedInteger('visits')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add uuid in migration

```
$table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
```

if you want to use uuid for foreign key you have to add

```
$table->uuid('ticket_type_id');
```

Comment: Thank you @Moolchand Sharma tell me I add the trait method like this example https://emymbenoun.medium.com/how-to-use-uuids-instead-of-auto-increment-ids-in-your-laravel-app-2e6cc045f6c1 will I need to alter or remove the following functions `getRouteKeyName`, `setSlugAttribute` and just keep `path()`

Comment: yes you can remove those methods from model and if you want to change primary key for all models then you can add getRouteKeyName function in your trait

Comment: Cool thank you but obviously path method is kept because that is what I use to get the path of the ticket. just need to change `$this->slug` to `$this->uuid` I think

Answer (score 0):

You can override `boot()` method of model and set closure to the `creating` event.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($user) {
        $user->uuid = (string) Str::uuid();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you I created a trait instead so I can use it in multiple models.